How to pass cookie to get request Robot framework with API (RequestsLibrary)
I want to use the cookie, received from the session in which I do POST request, in the next session with GET request, but I have problem.
Here is my keyword:
MY_Profile
    Log To Console    HEADER
    Log To Console    COOKIE
    Create Session    mySession         ${api_auth}    ${cookie}
    ${response}=      GET On Session    mySession      ${api_auth}
    Log To Console    ${response.status_code}

This is the error I received:

${cookie} is Unknown in this session


Also worth to point out besides my answer; you should pass the ${cookie} as argument to the keyword..

The keyword is defined as follows:

According to the docs, cookies is 4th argument to Create Session keyword. In your example, you are passing it in as 3rd so it ends up to headers.
So maybe pass it as kwarg:
   Create Session    mySession         ${api_auth}    cookies=${cookie}

Documentation is available here; https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-requests/doc/RequestsLibrary.html#Create%20Session
